# Thread class for exercises

Tags: java, beginner, multithreading

I just felt a sting as for the first time, I copy-pasted code blocks, and made very little change to it, to overload it. It works fine, but I have 3 constructors that are basically copy-pasted. I'm hoping there is a smarter way to do this.

This simply creates a thread and runs it with 1, 2 or 3 arguments, and then prints numbers to `System.out` using that thread. I will include an example usage below. The code doesn't strike me as bad of itself, but the sheer repetition is really bugging me. All criticism welcome.

```
import java.lang.Thread;

/**
 * Generic class that creates a thread and then loops and prints numbers to stdout.
 */
public class NumLoopThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thread;
    private String threadName;
    private int sleepTime = 400;
    private int numLoops = 10;

    /** Default constructor with threadName */
    public NumLoopThread(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
        thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
        thread.start();
    }
    /** Extra constructor with threadName and sleepTime */
    public NumLoopThread(int sleepTime, String threadName) {
        this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
        this.threadName = threadName;
        thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
        thread.start();
    }
    /** Extra constructor with threadName, sleepTime, and numberLoops */
    public NumLoopThread(int sleepTime, String threadName, int numberLoops) {
        this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.numLoops = numberLoops;
        thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
        thread.start();
    }
    /** Run the thread from start() */
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("%s starting%n", threadName);
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                System.out.printf("%s, i = %d%n", threadName, i);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.printf("%s ending%n", threadName);
    }
}
```

Example usage I wrote for an exercise (feel welcome to also criticize this, if you want). Looks like [this paste](http://pastebin.com/U2i4Z9Rc) after it's ran.

```
public class ThreadIsAlive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main thread starting");
        // create 3 running threads
        NumLoopThread t1 = new NumLoopThread(400, "t1");
        NumLoopThread t2 = new NumLoopThread(400, "t2");
        NumLoopThread t3 = new NumLoopThread(400, "t3");

        do {
            System.out.print(".");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        //wait until all threads terminate:
        } while (t1.thread.isAlive() ||
                 t2.thread.isAlive() ||
                 t3.thread.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Main thread ending");
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling `new Thread(this).start()` from the ctor. Not only does that leak `this` in the ctor, it has the potential to cause nasty issues with deadlocking. Consider refactoring this to some sort of `ThreadFactory` type pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Chained constructors.

I find it interesting that you described the single-parameter constructor as your "default" one, and the others as "extras". It's usually the other way around: the constructor that initializes all immutable fields is the "main" one, and any other constructor that works off default values would be "convenience" constructors.

> ```
> public NumLoopThread(int sleepTime, String threadName, int numberLoops) {
>     this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
>     this.threadName = threadName;
>     this.numLoops = numberLoops;
>     thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
>     thread.start();
> }
> ```

Take out `numberLoops`, you get this one:

```
public NumLoopThread(int sleepTime, String threadName) {
    // pasta
}
```

Take out `sleepTime`, you get this one:

```
public NumLoopThread(String threadName) {
    // pasta
}
```

Looks like `threadName` should be the first parameter in all 3 constructors, for consistency:

```
public NumLoopThread(String threadName, int sleepTime) {
    // pasta
}
```

```
public NumLoopThread(String threadName, int sleepTime, int numberLoops) {
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    this.threadName = threadName;
    this.numLoops = numberLoops;
    thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
    thread.start();
}
```

That way when you look at your overloads, they all look like they naturally extend each other, in some sort of *chain*.

You already have your defaults:

> ```
> private int sleepTime = 400;
> private int numLoops = 10;
> ```

Consider making them `static final`, and single-purpose:

```
private static final int defaultSleepTime = 400;
private static final int defaultNumLoops = 10;
```

And since the actual fields are only ever assigned in a constructor, they should be marked `final`, too:

```
private final int sleepTime;
private final int numLoops;
```

Use `this();` as the first instruction in the body, to "chain" the constructors:

```
public NumLoopThread(String threadName, int sleepTime) {
    this(threadName, sleepTime, defaultNumLoops);
}

public NumLoopThread(String threadName) {
    this(threadName, defaultSleepTime, defaultNumLoops);
}
```

Voilà, no more pasta!

---

That said I'm not sure about `start()`ing the thread in the constructor; it makes your `run` method a bit misleading. In general it is not a good idea to pass your 'this' reference to to a thread and start it during construction. The thread could then start with an unfinished object. Generally you should leave the starting of the thread to a separate method. [(ref)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=Safe%20Construction%20Practices%20java%20concurrency&source=bl&ots=uoZyy5tNhz&sig=qOaGaJM5Kfk3SPJgwYiJvJq_Ikw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdwJHH45_MAhXjk4MKHe7_AU0Q6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=Safe%20Construction%20Practices%20java%20concurrency&f=false)

Comment: ++ great answer but... Did you mean `DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME`?  ;-)

Comment: `WHATEVER_ROCKS_YOUR_BOAT` - you're probably right... althought I'd think `SHOUTING_SNAKE_CASE` would be for `const` things, right?

Comment: `final` is a const ;-)  try changing it later, the JVM will get real angry

Comment: Seconding what Phrancis said. In Java, there is no `const` keyword – it's replaced with `final`. Final public fields are constants and should therefore be `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE`.